# How to mock Base64 in Android?

Tags: android, junit, mocking, base64, mockito

I am writing a Unit test for a class that uses `android.util.Base64` and I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method encode in android.util.Base64 not mocked. See http://g.co/androidstudio/not-mocked for details.
at android.util.Base64.encode(Base64.java)
```

This is the code using the `encode()` method:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// [write some data to the stream]
byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.encode(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Now I understand that I can't use Android library classes in my Unit tests. But how do I correctly mock `Base64` so I can write a correct Unit test for my class?

Comment: Show how it is being used when you get the error.

Comment: Why do you need to mock it? That function is completely deterministic so you could probably write your tests in a way that checks some other property which you are actually interested in.

Comment: Suggest encapsulating the util behind an abstraction that can be mocked and explicitly injected into the subject under test.

Comment: @Nkosi I've considered that and I think it would make the code rather ugly.

Comment: I'd propose the same as @Nkosi. If you don't want to do this, you can use PowerMock for mocking static functions.

Comment: Found this which also supports @Christopher suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/39406002/5233410

Comment: I'll give PowerMock a try, thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: As suggested by link in error message https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#mocking-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the newer versions of Mockito you can also mock static methods. No need for powermockito anymore:

In gradle:

```
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:4.0.0"
testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:4.0.0"
```

In kotlin:

```kotlin
mockStatic(Base64::class.java)
`when`(Base64.encode(any(), anyInt())).thenAnswer { invocation ->
    java.util.Base64.getMimeEncoder().encode(invocation.arguments[0] as ByteArray)
}
`when`(Base64.decode(anyString(), anyInt())).thenAnswer { invocation ->
    java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(invocation.arguments[0] as String)
}
```

Answer (score 31):

I'm late but maybe that will help somebody.
For JUnit you can mock up the class without any third party lib. Just create a file Base64.java inside app/src/test/java/android/util with contents:

```
package android.util; 

public class Base64 {

    public static String encodeToString(byte[] input, int flags) {
        return java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(input);
    }

    public static byte[] decode(String str, int flags) {
        return java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(str);
    }

    // add other methods if required...
}
```

[image]

Comment: in my kotlin project I had to add `@file:JvmName("Base64")` at the very top of the file so that it gets picked up correctly

Comment: Please share some more detail of implementation.

Comment: @NaveenKumar you need just to create file Base64.java then put it in the directory, look at screenshot i've added

Comment: I copied directly the source of Base64.java from here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/util/Base64.java your version was a little too simple for my use case

Answer (score 8):

Based on the comments by Nkosi and Christopher, I have found a solution. I used PowerMock to mock the static methods of `Base64`:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Base64.class);
when(Base64.encode(any(), anyInt())).thenAnswer(invocation -> java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode((byte[]) invocation.getArguments()[0]));
when(Base64.decode(anyString(), anyInt())).thenAnswer(invocation -> java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode((String) invocation.getArguments()[0]));
```

And in my `build.gradle` I had to add:

```
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.4"
testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.4"
```

Note that not every version of Powermock works with every version of Mockito. The version I used here is supposed to work with Mockito `2.8.0-2.8.9`, and I have no issues. However, support for Mockito 2 is still experimental. There is a table detailing the compatible versions on [the project's wiki](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions).

Comment: I followed this approach but get an error in `DefaultMockHandler`, which could be due to an incompatible version of mockito. Which version of mockito are you using in your dependencies?

Comment: @PeterF Version 2.8.9: `testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'`

Comment: Various version configurations I tried didn't work well together. I now use     ``testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.0"``
    ``testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:2.0.0-beta.5'``
    ``testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-core:2.0.0-beta.5'``
    ``testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-beta.5'``
   `` testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5'``

Comment: Yeah, the compatibility is a bit tenuous. I have added a link to the versions table on Github to my answer. Thanks for sharing your configuration, I have not tried the beta myself.

Answer (score 3):

For Kotlin, you may use:

```
package android.util

import java.util.Base64


public object Base64 {
    @JvmStatic
    public fun encodeToString(input: ByteArray?, flags: Int): String {
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(input)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    public fun decode(str: String?, flags: Int): ByteArray {
        return Base64.getDecoder().decode(str)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this go?

Comment: You may create an android.util package in src/test source set. (which can be in app/src/test/java/android/util)

Answer (score 0):

If you run a test that calls an API from the Android SDK that you do not mock, you'll receive an error that says this method is not mocked. That's because the android.jar file used to run unit tests does not contain any actual code (those APIs are provided only by the Android system image on a device). Replace with java `Base64.getDecoder().decode()`.